# Node.js "/login" DB Error

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get "true" from hash compare. but a problem occurs when I write a username that does not exist in database.For example: if there is no "jack.33" as username, it is throwing mysql error and stopping the server. How can i block this error or create a solution?
Here is the error:

```
    throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
            ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined


app.post("/login", function(request, response) {
        var username = request.body.username;
        var pass = request.body.pass;

        con.query("select password from user where username = " + "\"" + username + "\"",function (err, result) {
            if(err) throw err;
            var passer = result[0].password;
            bcrypt.compare(pass, passer, function (err, res) {
                console.log(res);
                if (res === true) {
                    response.send("success")
                }else{
                    response.send("nop")
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: You need to check that the `result` array actually has stuff in it. The query can succeed but produce zero rows.

Comment: It looks like you are throwing this error yourself immediately after the query, are you catching it anywhere?

Comment: @tadman I'm checking it with if condition, but I can't stop the error, is there any possibility that to stop code after if(result === null) condition?

Comment: @Jarek Kulikowski yes, you're right. I'm thinking about how to send response message and stop it.

Comment: Samuel has an answer here that explains what I'm talking about. You need to check two conditions, you only check one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you got there was not thrown by your database driver.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined` is a typical error raised when the code expects a property that don't exist for an object.

Your `SELECT` query can return 0 or more rows and when nothing is returned, I suspect your database driver is giving you an empty array `[]`. Hence index 0 of `[]` would be `undefined`.

Now `undefined.password` will die with a similar error because the property `password` is not part of the `undefined` object.

Example:

```js
var result = []; // Assume SELECT query returns 0 row.
result[0].password;
```

Other than checking whether `err` is defined. Your code will also have to cater for scenario where user don't exist.

A simple check like `if result.length === 1` should fix your logic error.

You might wonder what if more than 1 row is returned? This is usually not possible unless you have a bad database design where usernames are not unique. In other words, you have a greater problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can also catch all uncaught errors globally.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log('UNCAUGHT', err.stack);
});
```

Comment: This is a solution to keep working, how can I use if(result === null){ response.send("nop") } and stop the process?

Comment: @AhmetAzizBeşli  process.exit();